# key press event in qt

Tags: qt, events

I wonder is there any difference between `Qt::ShiftModifier` and `Qt::Key_Shift`?
And what the difference between :

```
if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier){...}
```

and

```
if(event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier){...}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Qt::ShiftModifier` comes from the `Qt::KeyboardModifier` enum with a value of 0x02.
`Qt::Key_Shift` comes from the `Qt::Key` enum with a value of 0x01000020.

They're 'meaning' is the same, but they are used in different contexts.

```
if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier){...}
```

Does the modifiers bitfield *contain* a shift? This is just a standard C/C++ bit operation.

```
if(event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier){...}
```

Does the modifier bitfield *only contain* a shift?

Comment: thanks, so... modifier bitfield could contain not only one key?
e.g. the bitfield: A =  11001100
e.g. shift bitfield: S =  01001000
e.g. some key bitfield: K = 10001100
therefore, A & S is true and A & K is true, but S != K
so... what is better corrspond to the goal condition (we want to check if the Shift was pressed) if(... & ...) or if(... == ...) ?

Comment: It depends on the behaviour your trying to achieve; if you want to react *only* when Shift is held, then use the equality operator.  But if Shift + Ctrl is valid (even if you are only going to ignore Ctrl), then use the bitwise AND operator.  Generally the bitwise operator is sufficient.